# What's the best method for rendering a decoded frame?

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, bitmap, decode

After decoding and reaching to a frame, I need to know the best method for rendering it. I use Bitmap for this purpose, but every time I have to create a new bitmap, one for each frame. Maybe this is not the best method, since lots of memory is consumed and rebuilding bitmaps may take time. To clarify, I give the code:

```
ret = FFmpegInvoke.sws_scale(
    convertContext,
    &frame->data_0,
    frame->linesize,
    0,
    frame->height,
    &convertedFrame->data_0,
    convertedFrame->linesize);
Debug.Assert(ret >= 0);
var bmp = new Bitmap(dest_width, dest_height,
    convertedFrame->linesize[0], PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb,
    new IntPtr(convertedFrame->data_0));
pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```

I've added a picture box control to my form. I create a Bitmap from every decoded and converted frame's data and then set the picture box's image to the bitmap.
After finding the best method, and knowing whether I've done correctly, I need to know why is my problem with a background worker I put in the form. Apparently concurrent accessing to the bitmap object causes exception. Nevermind, first I need to make sure about this one.